# I'm unable to write unicode on PHP-CLI on the server

Tags: php

I specifically cannot add `åäö` to php-cli on the ubuntu server. I can write it in the terminal outside of the php-cli, I can create a file `test.php` and manually write:

```
<?php
echo "åäö";
```

And execute it with `php -f test.php` giving me the expected output. Looking at `phpinfp();` I have:

> default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
>
> mbstring.internal_encoding => UTF-8 => UTF-8
>
> LANG => en_US.UTF-8

I don't understand what's preventing me from passing charaters to PHP. What could be wrong?